# How to query with filter classifications

Tags: postgresql

Looking for a way to filter `clothes` based on their `labels`, the `labels` need to be considered for their classifications, such that different classification all needs to be satisfied (AND), same classification is joined (OR).

E.g. The following expectation can be satisfied:

Ask: (`Blue(classification: Color)` or `Green(classification: Color)`) and `On Sale(classification: Discount)`

or

Ask: `Blue(classification: Color)` and (`Aloha(classification: Style)` or `Knit(classification: Style)`)

Need help understand the best way to achieve this.

```
SELECT
    "clothes".*
FROM
    "clothes"
INNER JOIN "clothes_labels" ON
    "clothes_labels"."clothes_id" = "clothes"."id"
INNER JOIN "labels" ON
    "labels"."id" = "clothes_labels"."tag_id"
WHERE
    ...
```

[image]

Sample query fiddle (thank you):

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fd625a0f5b97a6e6b3067758aadcd434

Comment: Please tag only the database you are interested in.

Comment: Provide a sample as (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO) for all tables (at least 2-3 rows per table) and show desired output for this data (and some definite additional conditions) with explanations.

Comment: This is a typical EAV model; you need to join `label` multiple times, once for each classification.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, I would aggregate the labels for each clothe into a JSONB array which can then be queried for "contains all of this" quite easily.

Something along the lines:

```
select *
from clothes c
  join (
     select cl.clothes_id,
            jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(l) - 'id') as class
     from clothes_labels cl
       join labels l on cl.label_id = l.id
     group by cl.clothes_id
  ) cl on cl.clothes_id = c.id
where class @> '[{"name": "Blue", "classification": "color"},{"name": "Aloha", "classification": "style"}]'
   or class @> '[{"name": "Knit", "classification": "style"}]'
;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=526954d6e353f6dd3faeb3602500cbbe)

---

In general I would replace EAV models with a JSON approach these days as they tend to be easier to query and work with (again: assuming Postgres, in MySQL this can't be indexed efficiently)

Comment: Thank you Is there a way to accomplish this without using a JSONB aggregate?